# Uniform boundedness of Maclaurin Coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose $f(z)$ is a bounded in some region $|z|\leq R >1$ and analytic function and consider the Maclaurin series for $f$:
$$  f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n.$$ My question is:

1. What are the conditions on $f$ for $f^{(n)}(0)$ to be uniformly  bounded?
2. Do the uniform bounds for $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ exist under given conditions only?

I will be highly obliged for any clarifications/hints!

Comment: At least, conversely if $\{f^{(0)}\}$ is bounded, the radius of convergence  of the entire series in infinite. And if the radius of convergence is finite, the sequence can’t be bounded.

Comment: Asking for N&S conditions for 1) and 2) is asking for the sky.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ,I also had this hunch that it must be too notrivial .Anyways can we instead find some  bounds for $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$

Answer (score -1):

This is not a proper answer but an attempt to answer a related question. I would like to know whether there are any mistakes in my arguments.
**Convegence of $\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{f^n(0)}{n!}$** 
For $f $ as given we have the Maclaurin series for $f$ is given by
$$  f(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n.$$
Since $f$ is analytic and bounded  in $|z| \leq 1$, we have
$$ f(1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}.$$
As $f$ is analytic and $f(1)$ is bounded this means the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ converges to $f(1)$ and hence the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\right|$$ must be bounded which requires  $$\left|\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\right| \rightarrow 0$$ as $n$ goes to infinity?
Is the above conclusion valid for a bounded analytic function?

Comment: Consider the Maclaurin (and not Mclaurin) series $\log (1 + x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n+1} \frac{{x^n }}{n}}$. Note that $\log (2) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n+1} \frac{{1}}{n}}$, but $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty  \left|( - 1)^{n+1} \frac{{1}}{n}\right|=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty\frac{{1}}{n}$ is not bounded. Note also that you do not need to consider the series with absolute value. If $\sum a_n$ converges then $a_n \to 0$ necessarily.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out .We have ,however,$\left|\sum_{n = 0}^\infty  ( - 1)^{n+1} \frac{{1}}{n}\right|$ converges

Comment: Is the expresion for $f(1)$ correct?

Comment: the above is incorrect without additional hypothesis as for example $\exp(\frac{z+1}{z-1})=\sum a_nz^n$ is bounded by one on the unit disc but $f(1)$ doesn't exist; if $f$ is analytic on the closed disc (ie it has an extension at every point of the circle, then the radius of convergence is $1+\epsilon$ and the coefficients decay exponentially so the problem is trivial; this is though very confusing as the original problem is completely different since the condition implies $f$ entire of order at most $1$ and if order one, type at most $1$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your edifying clarification.

Comment: so Under the assumption R>1,can we conclude  the coefficients decay expontially?

Comment: yes because for example then $a_n(\frac{1+R}{2})^n \to 0$  (the decay is of the type $O_{\epsilon}((R-\epsilon)^{-n})$ for any $\epsilon$ - assuming $R$ finite, and the analogous for infinite radius when you have the decay to be $a_n=O_R(R^{-n})$ for every $R$; note however that the coefficients of the taylor series are $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ so the behavior of just $f^{(n)}(0)$ is a different issue

Comment: Yes indeed i noted the coefficients .Thanks once  more

Comment: the original question is different and as noted using the definition of the order of an entire function by coefficients you get that if $f^{(n)}(0)$ are bounded and at least infinitely many of them do not decay fast (so for example are bounded inferior in absolute value by some $c^{-n}$ the function has order one and finite type (and the type is one if the decay is now less than exponential so for example if infinitely many $|f^{(n)}(0)| >> P(n)^{-1}$ for some fixed nonzero polynomial; order $1$ doesn't ensure bounded derivatives, but order less than one ensures fast decaying ones